# Bower not copying any files

Tags: yeoman, bower

Im using bower as part of the yeoman 1.0 beta 4 install. All looks well however when I run bower install I get the expected output yet no files are copied to app/components as advertised.

I am running on windows which I understand is not officially supported yet. Has any one managed to get this up and running with some success? I have followed some tutorials on line relating to the subject however I think they are out dated. I managed to install yeoman without any additional steps and no errors as far as I can tell.

[Grunt File being Used](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3E58A9C22665FDCE!107&authkey=!ANwzBS_WW7SOigU)

Comment: Could you post your Gruntfile?

Comment: Grunt file attached in edit. thanks

Comment: I do have the same issue on Ubuntu Linux and Windows7. An older PC with WindowsVista don't have any trouble.
used versions:
yeoman 1.0 beta4
bower 0.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh no... Git was not on the system path. Adding it caused me to run into another small error with a solution found here http://wingkaiwan.com/2012/11/25/bower-errors-on-windows/

Thank you Mr Ricky Wan